# Eliminate duplicate urls (Web scraping RACE condition)

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, race-condition

I am trying to scarpe a website with 2 years, 2015and 2022.  I am trying to retrieve all pdf from below update. In each year we have many pdf Urls I am trying to insert data in {year: pdf_link} format. I am able to get URL but year is wrong. My assumption is because of threading

**For example:** : In the below screen shot for 2015 year we have  12-40968.pdf , but the same 12-40968.pdf is being generated for 2022 which is not there.

[image]

```
import os
from apify_client import ApifyClient
import concurrent.futures
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import requests
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import boto3
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import stat
import json
import ast
import threading
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def main():

    s3 = boto3.client('s3' )
    today_date=datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')                  
    generate_xmlfiles(s3,today_date)
    print("Uploaded successfully")

def generate_xmlfiles(s3,today_date):
    s3.put_object(Bucket='data', Key='Bany/'+today_date+"/xmlfiles.txt", Body=(str(scrape_data())))
    print("Exported files to s3")


def scrape_data():  
        years = [2022,2015]
        data = []
        states = ["alnb"]

        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
        options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
        options.add_argument("headless")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(#executable_path='/usr/src/app/chromedriver',
         options=options)
        # st = os.stat('/usr/src/app/chromedriver')
        # os.chmod('/usr/src/app/chromedriver', st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)
    
        with requests.Session() as session:
            for state in states:
                with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
                    futures = []
                    for year in years:
                        url = 'https://www.govinfo.gov/app/collection/uscourts/bankruptcy/'+state+'/'+str(year)+'/%7B%22pageSize%22%3A%22100%22%2C%22offset%22%3A%220%22%7D'
                        response = session.get(url)
                      #  print("response is"+str(response))
                        if response.status_code == 200:               
                            #  print(executor.submit(scrape_year, driver, url, state, year,data))     
                              futures.append(executor.submit(scrape_year, driver, url, state, year,data))  
                    for future in futures:
                      #  print("future is "+str(future.result()))
                        data += future.result()
                        print("hi")
                       # print(data)
    
                print("Loaded " +state)
        driver.quit()
        
        return data
    
def scrape_year(driver, url, state, year,data):
    print("scraping data for state "+state.capitalize() +" for "+str(year).capitalize())
    driver.get(url)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    try_count = 0
    while try_count < 3:
        try:
            elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "panel-body")))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
            bankruptcy_element = soup.findAll('div', {   "class":"panel-collapse collapse in","class":"panel-title","class":"panel-body","class":"panel panel-default", "class":"panel-collapse collapse in" ,"class":"btn-group-horizontal" })          
            return [{year:"https://www.govinfo.gov/metadata/granule"+xmlfile['href'].replace(".pdf","/mods.xml").replace("/pdf","").replace("/pkg/","/").replace("/content","")} for i in bankruptcy_element for xmlfile in i.findAll('a', href=True) if ("pdf" in (xmlfile['href']))]
        except TimeoutException:
                print(f"TimeoutException encountered. Retrying {try_count + 1} of 3...")
                try_count += 1
     
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I have updated parts of your code and it's now working for me.

- In `scrape_data()`

  Added

  ```
  futures.append(scrape_year(driver, url, state, year, data))
  ```

  instead of

  ```
  futures.append(executor.submit(scrape_year, driver, url, state, year,data))
  ```

  That is, I ignored `ThreadPoolExecutor` for serial execution, not parallel.
- In `scrape_year()`

  Added

  ```
  res = soup.find(attrs={"data-href": "/uscourts/bankruptcy/alnb/"+str(year)});
  bankruptcy_element = soup.findAll('div', {"id": "collapseOne"+res['id']})

  return [{year:"https://www.govinfo.gov/metadata/granule"+xmlfile['href'].replace(".pdf","/mods.xml").replace("/pdf","").replace("/pkg/","/").replace("/content","")} for i in bankruptcy_element for j in i.findAll('div', {"class":"btn-group-horizontal"}) for xmlfile in j.findAll('a', href=True) if ("pdf" in (xmlfile['href']))]
  ```